# Animation callbacks runs immediately even without the state being changed

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm creating an animation in angular, I need to know when it starts so I defined a callback. The thing is the callback is triggered when the component loads, even without changing the state.

Template

```
<button (click)="click()">click</button>
<div class="myclass" [@throwBall]="state" (@throwBall.start)="animStart($event)" >  
</div>
```

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('throwBall', [
      state('steady', style({ })),
      state('throw', style({ top: '300px' })),
      transition('steady => throw', [animate('2s')])
    ]),
    trigger('blockInitialRenderAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  state = 'steady';

  click() {
    this.state = 'throw';
  }
  animStart(event: any) {
    if (event.fromState !== 'void') {
      console.log('anim start callback');
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9szgic

Why is the 'anim start callback' being displayed in the console when the component loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial state of animation is a "stateless" state called `void` - which is the default state when using animations.
After initializing your `state` variable to `steady` a non-existing animation is starting from `void` -> `steady`.

In order to reach your goal, you should use properties `fromState` & `toState` of [AnimationEvent](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent).

```js
import { AnimationEvent, } from '@angular/animations';

public animStart(event: AnimationEvent): void {
   if(event.fromState === 'steady') {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Try to log `AnimationEvent` in your `animStart` method in order to better understand this `interface`.

```js
public animStart(event: AnimationEvent): void {
   console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: I took that approach but seems a bit dirty. Why is the callback called if there was no animation triggered? At least I haven't defined anything from void to 'steady'!

Comment: @Bonomi It fires an event for every transition that occures, so `void => 'steady'` also triggers a callback, even though you may not have defined an animation for it.

Comment: This is how Angular built my friend. VOID is very useful if you want to initiate some animation when the component is loaded. Just like we have "ngOnInit()".